# choosing between Multivariate, Univariate and Spline interpolation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, interpolation, spline

I have dataset of points with coordinates and temperature measured at each point.
I would like to interpolate the points to generate a continuous image.
[I have checked Scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html) and I have seen that there are different types of interpolation methods on scipy.

**what is the difference between Multivariate interpolation, Univariate interpolation and splines?When should I choose each one?**